# Django how to list_display an object by status in admin

Tags: django, admin

I have a model object say 'Category'. I allowed users to post Category item. The Category model has these:

models.py

```
LIVE_STATUS = 1
DRAFT_STATUS = 2
FOR_APPROVAL = 3

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (LIVE_STATUS, 'Live'),
    (DRAFT_STATUS, 'Draft'),
    (FOR_APPROVAL, 'For Approval'),
)


status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=FOR_APPROVAL,
    help_text=_("User posted reviews and categories are subject for approval. \
    Only entries with live status will be publicly displayed."))
```

Now im my admin.py

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = { 'slug': ['name'] }
    list_display = ('name','destinations', 'status', 'pub_date',)
    ordering = ('status', 'pub_date',)
    date_hierarchy = 'pub_date'
```

My problem is that I want to display Category items in admin separately/or by group via status. 
example:
list_display for live status
list_display for for approval status
list_display for live drafts status

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use list filters in your admin class. Add

```
list_filter = ('status',)
```

to your `CategoryAdmin` class. This should offer you the filter options 'All', 'Live', 'Draft' and 'For Approval' on a side bar right to the list of entries. Clicking one of them will filter the list accordingly. See also [The Django Admin site](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) and look for 'list_filter'.

Comment: thats it! Worked exactly. Thanks aldi.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the admin filters. Here is how: [Django Admin - List Filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)